# Согласование глагола

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

Имеется предложение:

> Большинство факелов, что висели на стенах напротив дверей, давно потухли.

Подскажите, с каким словом необходимо согласовывать слово "потухли"?

Потухло большинство или потухли факелы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Верно и *потухл**о***, и *потухл**и***. См. [Грамоту.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=291371):

> В состав подлежащего входит существительное со значением неопределенного
>   множества ряд, другие подобные слова – *большинство, меньшинство*,
>   часть. Сказуемое с подлежащим, включающим такие слова, может
>   согласовываться и в единственном числе, и во множественном (ср.: *Ряд
>   сотрудников отдела заявили, что они не согласны с позицией
>   администрации*). См. подробнее: Ю. А.
>   Бельчиков «Практическая стилистика современного русского языка» (М.,
>   2012), глава «Согласование сказуемого с подлежащим».

Answer (score 1):

Речь идет о согласовании сказуемого с подлежащим, выраженным существительным с собирательным количественным значением (большинство, часть, ряд и т.д.). В нашем случае между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит придаточное предложение с глаголом во множественном числе. В этом случае сказуемое обычно употребляется во **множественном числе**, хотя это и не обязательно.

**Большинство факелов, что висели на стенах напротив дверей, давно потухли.**

Cм: [Русский язык / Курс русского языка. Русский язык и культура общения / 3.3. Некоторые особенности согласования](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/783-33_nekotorye_osobennosti_soglasovaniya.html)